# facebook like button - both sdk and like provided script?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-like

Do i need both of these, as the facebook like button developer page isn't very clear:

like button - (i'm assuming Javascript SDK is brought in this way)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the sdk code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need both of them. The first code with the Like button code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

is enough.

When in doubt: [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: not using like box, but like button - and that's where I got the code. it just isn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I think it's clear enough, just use the code you were given and you'll be fine. If it's not clear for you, you can always test both and see by yourself